# Should the canonical link contain a link that will never change, the long version with keywords, or a shortened URL from another domain?

Tags: seo, redirects, html, canonical-url

I want to prevent SEO from duplicated content.  I have a separate domain only for shortened URLs which is mainly for sharing purpose.

I plan to set the `rel=canonical` in the HTML head and redirect to the long-version on request, identified through the unique content-id (similar how stackoverflow does).

Which URL should I advisedly point to, getting the highest potential in regard to SEO?
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.mainpage.com/content/1012921/">`
or
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.mainpage.com/content/1012921/this-is-the-original-and-long-version/">`
or
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://sho.rt/yd8eEndSX/">`

Content-id wont change, but Domain/TLD (even if not assumed to) could.
Shortend Domain/TLD won't never change.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller♦, Thank you for editing and improving the clarification. The fact asking for the shortened canonical link (from a separate domain) is imo not a duplicate of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109373/ since this topic is not included in the question. However they may both amount to the same thing, using short or long version, regardless if it is the same or separate domain, right?! :)

Comment: Your canonical link should be the one that you want users to see.  It doesn't matter if it changes occasionally.   You don't want your canonical to be the short version, either from your own site or from another domain.